# Using kineticJS to add drag and drop functionality to images drawn on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, draggable, kineticjs

I have a web page that I'm using to display a few images on and HTML5 canvas. I currently have the images displaying, and now want to make it possible to drag and drop the images around the canvas.

After looking into how to do this, it seems to me that the best way is to use the KineticJS library available at: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-an-image-tutorial/

I've looked into this, but I'm not really sure how to actually use it. 
I've started by including the script src in my index.html file, but how do I then apply the draggable property to the images I've displayed?

This is my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "kinetic.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<title>Home</title>

<script src = "drawLevelOneElements.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "layers&analytics.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "startGameDrawGameElementsDrawStartButton.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "interaction.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "dragAndDrop.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.0.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.1.2.js"></script>


</head>

<body onLoad="startGame()">

<section hidden>
<img id="StartButton" src="StartButton.png" alt="Start Button" width="179" height="180" href="javascript:drawLevelOneElements();"/>

<img id="building" src="images/assets/building.png" alt="Asset" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"/>
<img id="chair" src="images/assets/chair.gif" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="drink" src = "images/assets/drink.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="food" src = "images/assets/food.gif" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="fridge" src = "images/assets/fridge.png" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="land" src = "images/assets/land.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="money" src = "images/assets/money.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="oven" src = "images/assets/oven.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="table" src = "images/assets/table.gif" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="van" src = "images/assets/van.jpg" alt="Asset"/>

<img id="burger" src = "images/expenses/direct/burger.png" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="chips" src = "images/expenses/direct/chips.png" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="drink" src = "images/expenses/direct/drink.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="franchiseFee" src = "images/expenses/direct/franchiseFee.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="wages" src = "images/expenses/direct/wages.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>

<img id="admin" src = "images/expenses/indirect/admin.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="cleaners" src = "images/expenses/indirect/cleaners.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="electricity" src = "images/expenses/indirect/electricity.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="insurance" src = "images/expenses/indirect/insurance.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="manager" src = "images/expenses/indirect/manager.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="rates" src = "images/expenses/indirect/rates.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="training" src = "images/expenses/indirect/training.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="water" src = "images/expenses/indirect/water.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>

<img id="burger" src = "images/income/burger.png" alt="Income"/>
<img id="chips" src = "images/income/chips.png" alt="Income"/>
<img id="drink" src = "images/income/drink.jpg" alt="Income"/>

<img id="creditors" src = "images/liabilities/creditors.gif" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="electricity" src = "images/liabilities/electricity.png" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="food" src = "images/liabilities/food.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="hirePurchase" src = "images/liabilities/hirePurchase.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="loan" src = "images/liabilities/loan.png" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="overdraft" src = "images/liabilities/overdraft.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="payeTax" src = "images/liabilities/payeTax.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="tax" src = "images/liabilities/tax.jpg" alt="Liability"/>

</section>

    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>The purpose of this website is to teach users the basic principles of running a business by playing the game below. <br /><br /></p>

    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid">
    Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>

    <br /><br />
    <p>Use this paragraph to enter text that provides the user with instructions for how to play the game. <br />
        Update the instructions so that they're appropriate to whatever level the user is currently playing.</p>

    <script src = "variables&preloadingImages.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

and this is the function I'm using to draw the images to the canvas:

```
function drawLevelOneElements(){
            /*First, clear the canvas */ 
            context.clearRect(0, 0, myGameCanvas.width, myGameCanvas.height);
            /*This line clears all of the elements that were previously drawn on the canvas. */
            /*Then redraw the game elements */
            drawGameElements(); 
            /*Call the function to enable drag and drop */
            canvasState(document.getElementById('gameCanvas'));

            /*Create the four description areas, and place them near the bottom of the canvas */
            /*Create boxes with rounded corners for the description areas */
            CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawDescriptionArea = function(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke){
                if(typeof stroke == "undefined" ){
                    stroke = true;
                }
                if(typeof radius === "undefined"){
                    radius = 5;
                }
                this.beginPath();
                this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
                this.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
                this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
                this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
                this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
                this.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
                this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
                this.lineTo(x, y + radius);
                this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
                this.closePath();
                if(stroke){
                    context.stroke();
                }
            }

            context.drawDescriptionArea(70, 400, 120, 70);
            context.font = '25pt Calibri';
            context.strokeText('Asset', 90, 440);

            context.drawDescriptionArea(300, 400, 120, 70);
            context.strokeText('Liability', 310, 440);

            context.drawDescriptionArea(540, 400, 120, 70);
            context.strokeText('Income', 550, 440);

            context.drawDescriptionArea(750, 400, 180, 70);
            context.strokeText('Expenditure', 760, 440);

            /*Now draw the images to the canvas */
            /*First, create variables for the x & y coordinates of the image that will be drawn.
                the x & y coordinates should hold random numbers, so that the images will be 
                drawn in random locations on the canvas.*/
                var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
                var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
                var imageWidth = 50;
                var imageHeight = 50;

                /*Create a 'table' of positions that the images will be drawn to */
                var imagePositionsX = [20, 80, 140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560];
                var imagePositionsY = [20, 60, 100, 140, 180, 220, 260, 300, 340, 380];

            /*Draw all images from assetsImageArray */
            /*Use a while loop to loop through the array, get each item and draw it. */
            var arrayIteration = 0;
            console.log('All Images Array length: ' + allImagesArray.length); /*Display the length of the array in the console, to check it's holding the correct number of images. */
            while(arrayIteration < allImagesArray.length){
                //var randomPositionX = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                //var randomPositionY = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                context.drawImage(allImagesArray[arrayIteration], imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight); /*Declare variables for image height and width, so it can be accessed elsewhere */
                console.log(arrayIteration); /*Display the current array position that's being drawn */
                arrayIteration = arrayIteration+1;
                /*Now try changing the values of imageX & imageY so that the next image is drawn to a 
                    different location*/
                //imageX = imagePositionsX[randomPositionX];    /* imageX+(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)); */
                //imageY = imagePositionsY[randomPositionY];    /* imageY+(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));  */
                imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
                imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*350);

            }

        }
```

The while loop at the bottom of this function loops through the array where I've loaded all of the images I want to draw into the JavaScript, and draws each one to a random location on the canvas.

Since this is, in effect the point at which the images become JavaScript objects, I assume that this is where I need to set each one's 'draggable' property to true.

I've tried adding in the line

```
allImagesArray[arrayIteration].draggable = "true";
```

but then the browser console gives me the error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'draggable' of undefined".

Does anyone know why this is, and how I can put it right?

**Edit**

Ok, I've got rid of that error by moving the line `allImagesArray[arrayIteration].setDraggable = "true";` to just below the `context.drawImage...` line in the while loop, but I'm still not able to drag and drop the images around the canvas at all.

Does anyone know what I need to do to add the drag and drop functionality to the images?

Answer (score 0):

For the KineticJS to make the images draggable

1. They have to be in a KineticJS canvas, not in a custom canvas you've created.
2. They have to be added as [KineticJS Image object](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Image.php) instances, not drawn directly with `drawImage`.

See the [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-an-image-tutorial/).